# Trying to install grunt-cli, but need help to upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0

Tags: lodash, grunt-cli

I was working through the Thinkster Angular/Firebase tutorial and in the installation process I got to the part where I needed to install grunt-cli with this command in the terminal:

`npm install -g bower grunt-cli`

and got this error:

`lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0.`

How do I upgrade my lodash?

Comment: Please think about a better title.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the dependency chain. I guess grunt is still stocking to the older version of lodash. I think you should be fine as long as grunt is supporting it.

You find more info on this at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/20